# ImportError: No module named 'conda'

Tags: ubuntu, anaconda

I have problems with conda.

conda update conda:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/user/anaconda3/bin/conda", line 4, in <module>
  import conda.cli
ImportError: No module named 'conda'
```

which python:

```
/home/user/anaconda3/bin/python
```

It also does not help:

```
echo 'export PATH=$PATH:/home/user/anaconda3' >> ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: It has to be `/home/user/anaconda3/bin` that gets added to your PATH. But probably, that's already there since you have the right Python showing. Probably need to reinstall Anaconda, since you seem to be missing the conda module.